# Zig zag border for a circle?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Based on many tutorials I am able to create a zig zag border for square/rectangle objects using `:after` and `:before`. However when it comes to circles there are no tutorials at all.

I would like to create an object that looks like this:

[image: circle with zig-zag border]

Is that possible by using CSS only?

Comment: an online generator to easily get the code: https://css-generators.com/starburst-shape/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would consider using SVG with some rotation and use them as backgrounds.

Here is an attempt that can give you an idea about how it can be done. Basically, the SVG is the same and we simply repeat and rotate until we get the full shape. The main trick is to find the correct values:

[image]

Here is the final code:

```css
.zigzag {
   width:256px;
   height:256px;
   background:
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256'> <path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(16.36deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(32.73deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(49.09deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(65.45deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(81.81deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(98.18deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(114.54deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(130.90deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(147.27deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256' style='transform:rotate(164.2deg);'> <path  d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' /></svg>");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    
    font-size:28px;
    line-height:256px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="zigzag">
zig zag circle
</div>
```

---

You can also use it as a simple SVG. In this case, you can put all the paths inside the same SVG and apply rotation to them.

Here I used `calc` to calculate the value of rotation to better see the pattern. They will give the same values I used in the previous example:

```css
svg path {
 transform-origin: 12.5% 50%;
}

svg path:nth-child(1)  { transform:rotate(calc(0*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(2)  { transform:rotate(calc(1*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(3)  { transform:rotate(calc(2*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(4)  { transform:rotate(calc(3*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(5)  { transform:rotate(calc(4*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(6)  { transform:rotate(calc(5*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(7)  { transform:rotate(calc(6*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(8)  { transform:rotate(calc(7*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(9)  { transform:rotate(calc(8*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(10) { transform:rotate(calc(9*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(11) { transform:rotate(calc(10*(180deg/11)));}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256'> 
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
</svg>
```

Here is another attempt with more spikes and closer to your example. I simply reduced the width of the pattern by 2 and I increased their number by two:

[image]

```css
svg path {
 transform-origin: 12.5% 50%;
}

svg path:nth-child(1)  { transform:rotate(calc(0*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(2)  { transform:rotate(calc(1*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(3)  { transform:rotate(calc(2*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(4)  { transform:rotate(calc(3*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(5)  { transform:rotate(calc(4*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(6)  { transform:rotate(calc(5*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(7)  { transform:rotate(calc(6*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(8)  { transform:rotate(calc(7*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(9)  { transform:rotate(calc(8*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(10) { transform:rotate(calc(9*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(11) { transform:rotate(calc(10*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(12) { transform:rotate(calc(11*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(13) { transform:rotate(calc(12*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(14) { transform:rotate(calc(13*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(15) { transform:rotate(calc(14*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(16) { transform:rotate(calc(15*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(17) { transform:rotate(calc(16*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(18) { transform:rotate(calc(17*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(19) { transform:rotate(calc(18*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(20) { transform:rotate(calc(19*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(21) { transform:rotate(calc(20*(180deg/22)));}
svg path:nth-child(22) { transform:rotate(calc(21*(180deg/22)));}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256'> 
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M40 240 L40 16 L32 0 L24 16 L24 240 L32 256 Z' />
</svg>
```

You can also easily adjust the size of the spikes.

[image]

```css
svg path {
 transform-origin: 12.5% 50%;
}

svg path:nth-child(1)  { transform:rotate(calc(0*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(2)  { transform:rotate(calc(1*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(3)  { transform:rotate(calc(2*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(4)  { transform:rotate(calc(3*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(5)  { transform:rotate(calc(4*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(6)  { transform:rotate(calc(5*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(7)  { transform:rotate(calc(6*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(8)  { transform:rotate(calc(7*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(9)  { transform:rotate(calc(8*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(10) { transform:rotate(calc(9*(180deg/11)));}
svg path:nth-child(11) { transform:rotate(calc(10*(180deg/11)));}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256'> 
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
<path d='M48 220 L48 36 L32 0 L16 36 L16 220 L32 256 Z' />
</svg>
```

---

As a side note, I have used [`path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path) to create the pattern but since it's an easy shape we can also do it with [`polygon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) using almost the same syntax:

```css
svg {
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256'> 
<path d='M48 240 L48 16 L32 0 L16 16 L16 240 L32 256 Z' />
</svg>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-97 0 256 256' fill='orange' width='256'> 
<polygon points='48,240 48,16 32,0 16,16 16,240 32,256' />
</svg>
```

Comment: Agreed. There's no justification for doing this in CSS. It may be possible in CSS (likely using a similar technique to the SVG in this answer), but it certainly wouldn't be easy to achieve or to maintain. CSS isn't the answer here: browsers have perfectly good SVG support; use it.

Comment: @Spudley The only justification for trying this using only CSS is the challenging part ;) we may end with a *crazy* code but it can be a good practise to learn more CSS tricks. But this time, I didn't find that crazy code :p

Comment: "learn more CSS tricks": why bother learning something you can't use in real life?  If you use them you make a monster to maintain at the very best. So let's just not bother with trickery.

Comment: @swa66 you don't necessary need to use them in the real world .. when our teachers gave us homework to do and things to solve we are not going to use them in the real world. We will simply learn a new trick that we can use somewhere else ... If we only learn things that we will use in the real world then we will learn a little. Trickery will make our brain thing about a way to solve issues that we may face in the real world.

Comment: But the whole point is that CSS tricks are bad, very, very, very bad practice and should never be used anywhere. Learning it and spreading inevitably leads to somebody thinking it's ok to actually use it. And that is *never* the case. So yes, "css tricks are evil". And the practice needs to be shunned completely.
This isn't something that can have some use down the road.

Comment: @swa66 this your opinion. Check all the answers of this question and see what are the tricks used: transform, SVG, clip-path, multiple background, some math, etc etc ... so trying to solve this using CSS you will make you learn all these stuffs that you can use separately or together. It's no about to only learn how to create this shape BUT to learn the techniques behind. We can easily build such shape using Photoshop then add it as background. Very easy but nothing new added to our knowledge.

Comment: I've no problem with knowing, teaching and learning e.g. SVG. Nor learning about CSS etc. What I have a problem with is a culture where "tricks" are glorified as that leads inevitably to serious trouble down the road. It's exactly the same when people discovered you could do layout with tables. It was a trick: tables were intended to show data in a 2D grid, not do layout. But some found this "trick" and started to use it ... 
Use what stuff is intended to be used for. Not because it's easy, but because it's the right thing to do. Leave no room whatsoever for trickery, it only leads to trouble

Comment: @TemaniAfif There was already a clear and concise set of answers for this. I know this is a new answer but directing to the old question is much better for SO and reducing duplication. Ive seen this done a couple of times so can you make sure that there are no duplicates first. Someone with your amount of rep should know their way around SO to find dupes easy enough.

Comment: @Stewartside seaching for a duplicate is the first thing I do and if I have found one I would already closed as dupe (as a side note, I am one of the top hammer dupe on the site  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/425986/close-stats-for-top-dup-hammer-users and I only got the Gold badge in Feb) ... And you was able to find that dup because you have answered it already and you may notice there is no releveant keyword in such question to easily find it, even with image search in google I was not able to find a relevant one.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a (jagged) circle with triangles. The idea is to create an equilateral triangle inscribed inside the circle, create copies of it and rotate them around the center. The following figure explains how the sides of the triangle are calculated:

[image: inscribed equilateral triangle]

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

/*
 * triangle border left/right = 50px * cos(30°)
 * triangle border bottom = 50px + 50px * sin(30°)
 */

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6.7px;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 43.3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 43.3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 75px solid #BF9020;
  transform-origin: center 50px;
}

.triangle:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(10deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(20deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(30deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(5) { transform: rotate(40deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(6) { transform: rotate(50deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(7) { transform: rotate(60deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(8) { transform: rotate(70deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(9) { transform: rotate(80deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(10) { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(11) { transform: rotate(100deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(12) { transform: rotate(110deg); }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Once you're able to get your head around the above example ***use the fluid version below***:

```css
.circle {
  width: 80vh;
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6.7%;
  top: 0;
  width: 86.6%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: #BF9020;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
  transform-origin: center 66.6%;
}

.triangle:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(10deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(20deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(30deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(5) { transform: rotate(40deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(6) { transform: rotate(50deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(7) { transform: rotate(60deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(8) { transform: rotate(70deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(9) { transform: rotate(80deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(10) { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(11) { transform: rotate(100deg); }
.triangle:nth-child(12) { transform: rotate(110deg); }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is to use `clip-path` property:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.clipped {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 46.93% 3.1%, 43.47% 0.43%, 40.83% 3.9%, 37.06% 1.7%, 34.89% 5.49%, 30.87% 3.81%, 29.21% 7.85%, 25% 6.7%, 23.89% 10.92%, 19.56% 10.33%, 19.01% 14.66%, 14.64% 14.64%, 14.66% 19.01%, 10.33% 19.56%, 10.92% 23.89%, 6.7% 25%, 7.85% 29.21%, 3.81% 30.87%, 5.49% 34.89%, 1.7% 37.06%, 3.9% 40.83%, 0.43% 43.47%, 3.1% 46.93%, 0% 50%, 3.1% 53.07%, 0.43% 56.53%, 3.9% 59.17%, 1.7% 62.94%, 5.49% 65.11%, 3.81% 69.13%, 7.85% 70.79%, 6.7% 75%, 10.92% 76.11%, 10.33% 80.44%, 14.66% 80.99%, 14.64% 85.36%, 19.01% 85.34%, 19.56% 89.67%, 23.89% 89.08%, 25% 93.3%, 29.21% 92.15%, 30.87% 96.19%, 34.89% 94.51%, 37.06% 98.3%, 40.83% 96.1%, 43.47% 99.57%, 46.93% 96.9%, 50% 100%, 53.07% 96.9%, 56.53% 99.57%, 59.17% 96.1%, 62.94% 98.3%, 65.11% 94.51%, 69.13% 96.19%, 70.79% 92.15%, 75% 93.3%, 76.11% 89.08%, 80.44% 89.67%, 80.99% 85.34%, 85.36% 85.36%, 85.34% 80.99%, 89.67% 80.44%, 89.08% 76.11%, 93.3% 75%, 92.15% 70.79%, 96.19% 69.13%, 94.51% 65.11%, 98.3% 62.94%, 96.1% 59.17%, 99.57% 56.53%, 96.9% 53.07%, 100% 50%, 96.9% 46.93%, 99.57% 43.47%, 96.1% 40.83%, 98.3% 37.06%, 94.51% 34.89%, 96.19% 30.87%, 92.15% 29.21%, 93.3% 25%, 89.08% 23.89%, 89.67% 19.56%, 85.34% 19.01%, 85.36% 14.64%, 80.99% 14.66%, 80.44% 10.33%, 76.11% 10.92%, 75% 6.7%, 70.79% 7.85%, 69.13% 3.81%, 65.11% 5.49%, 62.94% 1.7%, 59.17% 3.9%, 56.53% 0.43%, 53.07% 3.1%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box clipped"></div>
```

As mentioned in another answer - the tricky part is figuring out the right values.
I didn't pick them by hand - check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/gjjxdP?editors=0012) to see how they are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP asked for a CSS only solution, however I feel like for some people here, a `<svg>` would suffice. So in that case you can use a `<svg>` element with a `<polyline>` like so:

```html
<svg
   viewBox="0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve" width="100" height="100"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <polygon
        points="500,250 473.216,279.409 491.536,314.718 458.049,336.172 466.532,375.03 428.619,387.055     426.778,426.778 387.044,428.619 375.02,466.543 336.161,458.049 314.707,491.547 279.409,473.226 250,500 220.581,473.226     185.282,491.547 163.818,458.049 124.959,466.543 112.945,428.619 73.222,426.778 71.371,387.044 33.458,375.021 41.941,336.172     8.453,314.718 26.774,279.409 0,250 26.774,220.591 8.453,185.282 41.941,163.829 33.458,124.97 71.371,112.956 73.222,73.222     112.956,71.381 124.97,33.468 163.829,41.952 185.282,8.463 220.581,26.784 250,0 279.409,26.784 314.718,8.463 336.172,41.962     375.03,33.468 387.044,71.381 426.778,73.232 428.619,112.966 466.532,124.98 458.049,163.839 491.536,185.282 473.216,220.591       " style="fill:#0171a5;" />
</svg>

<div style="margin-top: 10px;">

</div>

<svg
   viewBox="0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve" width="100" height="100"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path stroke="blue" fill="white" stroke-width="15"
        d="M 500,250 473.216,279.409 491.536,314.718 458.049,336.172 466.532,375.03 428.619,387.055     426.778,426.778 387.044,428.619 375.02,466.543 336.161,458.049 314.707,491.547 279.409,473.226 250,500 220.581,473.226     185.282,491.547 163.818,458.049 124.959,466.543 112.945,428.619 73.222,426.778 71.371,387.044 33.458,375.021 41.941,336.172     8.453,314.718 26.774,279.409 0,250 26.774,220.591 8.453,185.282 41.941,163.829 33.458,124.97 71.371,112.956 73.222,73.222     112.956,71.381 124.97,33.468 163.829,41.952 185.282,8.463 220.581,26.784 250,0 279.409,26.784 314.718,8.463 336.172,41.962     375.03,33.468 387.044,71.381 426.778,73.232 428.619,112.966 466.532,124.98 458.049,163.839 491.536,185.282 473.216,220.591 z"/>
</svg>
```